# ASP.NET 5 Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, windows, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I used Visual Studio 2015, to build an ASP.NET 5 web application project. I selected windows authentication, which seems to be working fine for IIS Express. But when deployed to IIS 8.5, I am getting null for `@User.Identity.Name.`

Also, I used ASP.Membership for custom roles with windows authentication before. How would i go about custom roles with windows authentication for ASP.NET 5

Comment: Could you provide the code of your Startup class (Configure + ConfigureServices methods)? Also could you provide more detail about how you published the web app to IIS 8.5? Aplication pool settings etc.

Comment: Found the issue - at IIS root level anonymous authentications was enable. I just disabled and it worked. :)